# How to load self-written package documentation with '?my_package_name'?

Tags: r, package, documentation

I made a package in R called "my_package_name". When I run `?my_package_name` or `??_my_package_name`, no results are found. I want a help file to be loaded in the same way that `?ggplot2` loads a package help file.

I can run `?my_function_name` to obtain the help files for my functions. However, this does not work with my package name, even though the description file is complete. I found that `help(package = my_package_name)` loads a page that contains the description file and help pages, but I would like load a page with `?my_package_name`.

Comment: How are you loading your package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the easiest way is probably to run the following from the `usethis` package. It will create the file needed to have your package documentation

```
usethis::use_package_doc()
```

I suggest reading the documentation of the function to understand what's going on under the hood.